# Is there a Google Assistant plugin for Unity?

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

I'm looking for a Unity3d plugin for Google Assistant for a potential upcoming project.  Does one exist?

If not, is there one for Unreal?

If not...well blah.

Comment: A quick Google search returns no helpful results. It seems like none exist at this time, but it may provide you with an opportunity to create one.

Comment: Yeah, I did try google before posting this and got the same result. I noticed there’s something for unreal, but that seems more like a hobbyist’s plug-in than anything official